# Only root sees all icons in gnome-control-center after upgrade to Lubuntu 13.04

Tags: lubuntu, 13.04, gnome-control-center

**Symptoms:**

```
root@ThinkPad:/# gnome-control-center
```

=> `gnome-control-center` opens correctly showing all modules

```
root@ThinkPad:/# gnome-control-center sound
```

=> `gnome-control-center` opens the sound panel

```
anynormaluser@ThinkPad:~$ gnome-control-center
```

=> `gnome-control-center` opens showing **only 3** modules: languages, printers, software

```
anynormaluser@ThinkPad:~$ gnome-control-center sound

** (gnome-control-center:12466): WARNING **: Could not find settings panel "sound"
```

All files/dirs in 
`/usr/share/gnome-control-center` and `/usr/lib/control-center-1/panels`
are readable/executable for all users.

**Tries:**

Re-installed `gnome-control-center` with synaptic.

Result: problem is still the same!

Made an strace as non-root user:

```
...
open("/usr/share/applications/gnome-sound-panel.desktop", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
fstat64(15, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=634, ...}) = 0
read(15, "[Desktop Entry]\nName=Sound\nComme"..., 4096) = 634
...
open("/usr/share/applications/gnome-sound-nua-panel.desktop", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
fstat64(15, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=636, ...}) = 0
read(15, "[Desktop Entry]\nName=Sound\nComme"..., 4096) = 636
...
```

Any user can read the sound panel desktop files, but the icons are not shown either!

How to get rid of this problem ?

How does `gnome-control-center` "find" its modules ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are running other environments than Gnome, the icons are invisible due to a directive in Gnome's desktop files.

See **/usr/share/applications/gnome*panel.desktop**

and search in the files for the line

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
```

You could remove this line or append your environment to the list.
The possible values are listed here:

> http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apb.html

For Unity you can simply install **unity-control-center** which resolves that situation for you automatically:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Comment: Thanks. I had uninstalled `evolution` (because I don't use it and have no use for the unity stuff that uses it like signing into facebook, etc.), and it must have uninstalled `unity-control-center`, too. I reinstalled `unity-control-center` (and the `evolution` stuff), and now `gnome-control-center` works as expected. Thanks!